# Carousel swipe not working for iframe video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using carousel swipe function to move slide images. When I start to move for video section video start to play instead of moving to next.

```
<div id="carousel-banner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-banner" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-banner" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-banner" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/main-banner.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/main-banner.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item bg-frame id='thevideo' style='display:none'">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PLAI6HmLGuk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>                       
                </div>
                <div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'"><img src="img/main-banner.png" style="cursor:pointer" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried below carosuel script

```
$(".carousel").swipe({
      swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
        if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
        if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');
      },
      allowPageScroll:"vertical"
    });
```

[my demo code here](http://orderonline.my/designer/carosuel/)

Comment: You'd probably need to show your video code as well - there's not even a mention of `video` in your above code. Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code Mr.@ObsidianAge

Answer (score 1):

The proplem is iframe video click over swipe event.
Basically, i will try to fix it via overlay and simple js.
here is a little demo

```js
/*

dependencies:

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js

*/
$(".iframeSwipe").click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("overlay");
  $("#video")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  $(".carousel").carousel("pause");
  event.preventDefault()
});



$(".carousel").swipe({

  swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {

    if (direction == 'left') $(this).carousel('next');
    if (direction == 'right') $(this).carousel('prev');

  },
  allowPageScroll: "vertical"

});
```

```css
/*
     ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ

*/

.overlay::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.touchswipe/1.6.4/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 default carousel with swipe and touch gestures</h1>
    <p class="lead">How to add the swipes gesture to comand the Bootstrap 3 carousel on mobile devices.</p>
    <p>Made by <strong>Andrea Rufo</strong>, more info and tutorial on <a href="http://www.andrearufo.it/">andrearufo.it</a></p>
  </div>


  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=62">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622">
      </div>
      <div class="item iframeSwipe overlay">
        <iframe id="video" width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PLAI6HmLGuk?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

User can swipe and still  play video after click video iframe(overlay) .
Hope my answer help you :)

Comment: here when I swipe the video get start automatically play. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: i just add 
    $(".carousel").carousel("pause");  
to my js ,try this?

Comment: maybe you can see my codepen link 
https://codepen.io/Not2Day2Die/pen/GyVRye
i'm not really good at stackoverflow code insert

Comment: which place I need to insert $(".carousel").carousel("pause"); this to avoid video autoplay when swipe

Comment: in my code  https://codepen.io/Not2Day2Die/pen/GyVRye , is in the end of  $(".iframeSwipe").click function .
my idea is carousel shoud stop automatically play after user click iframe video .

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: @John sorry i missunderstood you problem lol , i modify my code , would you accept dblcilck ? if you do ,things become easy. try this 
https://codepen.io/Not2Day2Die/pen/GyVRye

Comment: no problem Mr . Still the swipe not working anyway once again thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: This approach has a significant limitation - it prevents the user from interacting with any of the YouTube player controls.